# how to make an enemy move towards the player within a certain range using navmesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been attempting to add a "range" of sorts to my enemy movement (too many move toward the player at once) and I have seen one solution but I am uncertain how to implement it as it doesn't really detect that I'm using the dis and distval values.

I am not trying to add any movement or route for them to follow. Just a wide (but not too wide) activation sphere of sorts. (also note that I am new, and I know it's probably a stupid question to ask, but I still don't know the answer to it and can't find it ((or at the very least understand it))).

here is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent enemy;
    public Transform Player;
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var distVal = 5.0f;
        var dis = Vector3.Distance(enemy.position, Player.position);

        if (dis <= disVal)
        {
            enemy.SetDestination(Player.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add a `SphereCollider` at the player and enemy and make it a trigger you can use `OnTriggerEnter`. This way you get access to the other's collider and so eachother's position. No distance check needed, that already occured. Would place this code on the player in the mentioned method. Mind, when this trigger occurs the player will probably run away or something, the enemy will go to the position which is outdated. Sometimes the wanted behaviour but it wouldn't chase the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a NavMeshAgent's destination to be its own position it will stop moving.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent enemy;    
    public Transform Player;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distVal = 5.0f;
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(enemy.transform.position, Player.position);

        if (dist <= distVal)
        {
            enemy.SetDestination(Player.position);
        }
        else
        {
            enemy.SetDestination(enemy.transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

This should do what you want. But I should point out you were never using your distVal variable, and that enemy.position should have been enemy.transform.position.